# FilterPredicates do not currently support repeated in spark 3x

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I can't filter in array column in spark 3.2.0

Query:

`df.filter(col("src").getItem(0).equalTo("uid2")).show(false)`

But it return Exception:

```
WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 36) (hadoop4964 executor 2): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FilterPredicates do not currently support repeated columns. Column src is repeated.
```

Who can help me fix it?

Comment: Could you show a few lines of `df` please?

Comment: @leleogere 

|1662300028|        183.80.57.73|[admttd]|3399737987712234446|[fa6a6cee-8d66-4b...|  true|

Comment: Add is in the question for everyone please, it will be easier to read

Comment: Can you provide more details please. print the dataframe structure using df.printSchema() and post your config

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Guy Melul answered me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be an issue in Spark 3.2.X.

See here: https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@spark.apache.org/msg29086.html

downgrading will solve this issue, you can also try to upgrade to 3.3.X and see if the issue persist (I believe it will)

Meanwhile a workaround would be to disable predicate pushdown for parquet

`spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown=false`